# Share in inheritance

Tags: inheritance

Does a woman(Widow) lose her share in her deceased husband's property if she marries after Iddat?

I know a widow whose parents are reluctant for her second marriage, as her late husband was wealthy, and they fear that If she re marries , her share of inherritance from 1st husband will be cancelled. Please guide thoroughly.

Answer (score 1):

If a man dies from a woman who inherited his estate according to the legal inheritance, and does not terminate her marriage with another person after her right to inherit from her first husband by consensus of the Muslims.
**The wife has a share of the estate of her deceased husband; whether she married after him or did not marry**

> ﴿ لِلرِّجَالِ نَصِيبٌ مِمَّا تَرَكَ الْوَالِدَانِ وَالْأَقْرَبُونَ
>   وَلِلنِّسَاءِ نَصِيبٌ مِمَّا تَرَكَ الْوَالِدَانِ وَالْأَقْرَبُونَ
>   مِمَّا قَلَّ مِنْهُ أَوْ كَثُرَ نَصِيباً مَفْرُوضاً ﴾

women should marry after her husband death if she has lust and can't control her self even if the husband say to her she should not marry,or if she has children and she can not take care of them